# npm license-checker and windows

Tags: javascript, windows, npm

So, i wanted to use the **[npm license-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/license-checker)** on a package.json in a specific folder in a project. But it did not work, because the command "**license-checker**" is wrong or not found. I was in the directory, that i wanted to "check". I tried "npm install -g license-checker" (global) and "npm install license-checker" (local)  in the folder.

I am on a windows computer.

How can i get the **license-checker** to work?

---

**Edit:**

1. I ran `license-checker` after the installation, in the same terminal.
2. I've also tried opening a new session, i.e. in a new terminal window, then `cd` to my project directory and run the `license-checker` command again. However,  it still does not find `license-checker`.

Comment: FYI java and javascript are two completely disparate languages.

Comment: Thank you, but my part of the code is written in java, that is why i tagged java, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

1. I had to go to the user variables and add **Name**="NODE_PATH" **Value**="C:\Users\theduc\AppData\Roaming\npm"
2. Next i added to "**PATH**": "C:\Users\theduc\AppData\npm"
3. I also added to the system variables **Name**="A NAME" **Value**="run control.exe sysdm.cpl,System,3"
4. I went to my IDE(Intellij) to **File->Settings->Tools->Terminal->Enviroment Variables** and add a new user enviroment variable: **Name**="A NAME" **Value**="C:\Users\theduc\AppData\npm"
5. **Invalidate** and **restart** IDE
6. Restart computer and it worked!